# Cannot access ParseFile from User class in parse from android. Only other classes

Tags: android, image, parse-platform, download

I cannot access the photo that I saved in the User class in parse from android using the code below. If I add a new class to parse and use this exact code, it downloads the picture fine. However, it just won't allow me to pull from the User Class/Table in parse. Why is this and how do I fix it? Do I need to use a pointer? If so, how? Thanks.

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
            "User");


    query.getInBackground("JkANnvy77y",
            new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

                public void done(ParseObject object,
                                 ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object
                            .get("pictest");
                    fileObject
                            .getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                                public void done(byte[] data,
                                                 ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        Log.d("test",
                                                "We've got data in data.");
                                        // Decode the Byte[] into
                                        // Bitmap
                                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory
                                                .decodeByteArray(
                                                        data, 0,
                                                        data.length);

                                        // Get the ImageView from
                                        // main.xml
                                        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView6);

                                        // Set the Bitmap into the
                                        // ImageView
                                        image.setImageBitmap(bmp);



                                    } else {
                                        Log.d("test",
                                                "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
```

Update: I edited the code to allow me to print the parseexception to logcat and it is telling me that no query was found! GRR

Answer (score 0):

here is my code from another project, adapt it to your needs

```
  //get all images
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (objects.size() > 0) {
                if (e == null) {
                    if (!objects.isEmpty()) {
                       //we have grabbed all the users
                      //now lets try to get a file
                    ParseFile file=  (ParseUser)objects.get(0).ParseFile("image");

                    } else if (e.getCode() == ParseException.REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED) {
                        makeSnack("Error! Reloading images.");

                    } else {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.v("error", e.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    //TODO:// if not images, reregister loclistener
                    makeSnack("No images located near you.");
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```